# AllItems listview web page

Tags: sharepoint, listview, web-parts, defaultview

I am trying to create a custom default view for a list. I made a copy of my list's AllItems.aspx page, and renamed it, and inserted a CEWP onto the page, as I would like to use jQuery to display a color in a column field similar to http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/04/sharepoint-calculated-column-and-jquery.html. The issue I am having is that when I save my changes and check in the new page, SharePoint removes all of the web parts that were on my page.

Why is this happening, and how do I stop it from removing my webparts?

UPDATE: Still not definitely sure why, but I noted that it stopped doing this when I changed the filename to something different, instead of the default copied filename which I had been using before.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a content editory query web part to change the color of an item, have you considered using conditional formatting which you can do via SharePoint designer?

Comment: I have never been able to get the conditional formatting thing to work b/c of the XPath expressions. I haven't really wanted to spend time learning them, so I just went the jQuery route which I know works.  Do you know of any good XPath tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

Try this article for steps .. but I will also suggest you drop the idea of CEWP and use conditional formatting.

http://snahta.blogspot.com/2010/08/listview-from-other-site-collection.html